# Props passed to child components returned as undefined in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, undefined, nuxt.js, lifecycle, vue-props

I have a child component inside of a form that takes an object as a prop from the parent component. This object is being used to store data entered from the user via input and is emitted whenever the user types. Now I will be honest, I'm not 100% sure that the emitting works just yet. This is due to the fact that when I attach properties of the object to v-model inside an input element, Nuxt shows an error saying

> Cannot read property 'insert property here' of undefined

What puzzles me is the fact that if I look inside of Vue dev tools, it's shown clearly that the prop is received. I can view all of its properties when I click the child component, yet when I try to reference it I am given an error.

Here is how I pass the data to the child component from the parent file.

```
<NewProjectIterations
  v-for="i in iterations"
  :key="i"
  :index="i"
  v-model="iterationsData[i]"
/>
```

Here is the javascript

```
export default {
  name: 'NewProject',
  components: {
    NewProjectIterations
  },
  data() {
    return {
      iterations: 2,
      payoutAmount: null,
      projectName: null,
      emailAssigned: null,
      iterationsData: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    // Computed property that keeps all the form data inside of one object
    formData() {
      return {
        user: this.$store.auth.user._id,
        projectName: this.projectName,
        payoutAmount: this.payoutAmount,
        payoutDividedInto: this.iterations,
        emailAssigned: this.emailAssigned,
        iteration: this.iterationsData
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // Initialize the child components data object on mount inorder to store user submit data
    const object = {
      name: '',
      title: '',
      startDate: null,
      endDate: null,
      payoutAmount: this.payoutAmount / this.iterations,
      filesAttachhed: null,
      index: null
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.iterations; i++) {
      object.index = i + 1
      this.iterationsData.push(object)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increaseIteration() {
      if (this.iterations > 5) {
        alert('Iterations cannot be more than 5, nice try')
        return
      }

      const object = {
        name: '',
        title: '',
        startDate: null,
        endDate: null,
        payoutAmount: this.payoutAmount / this.iterations,
        filesAttachhed: null,
        index: this.iterations + 1
      }

      this.iterationsData.push(object)
      this.iterations = this.iterations++
    },
    removeIteration() {
      if (this.iterations > 1) {
        alert('Iterations must be more than 1, nice try')
        return
      }
      this.iterations = this.iterations--
      this.iterationsData.pop()
    },
    removeIterationByIndex(index) {
      this.iterations = this.iterations--
      this.iterationsData.splice(index)
      this.iterationsData.forEach(({ index }, i) => {
        index = i + 1
      })
    },
    async submitProject() {
      // Submit the data and make a request to the backends API through Vuex & store the data 
      // inside of a database
      await this.$store.dispatch('projects/createNewProject', this.formData)
    }
  }
```

Finally here is the `<NewProjectIteration />` single file component.

```
<template>
  <div :id="index" class="New-Project-Iteration">
    <div class="New-Iteration-Upper-Half">
      <div class="New-Iteration-Index">
        <p>{{ index + 1 }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="New-Interation-Header">
        <input
          id="title"
          v-model="value.name"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Title"
          name="title"
          style="display: block"
        />
        <input
          id="date"
          v-model="value.startDate"
          placeholder="Start"
          class="textbox-n"
          type="text"
          onfocus="(this.type='date')"
          onblur="(this.type='text')"
        />
        -
        <input
          id="date"
          v-model="value.endDate"
          placeholder="Deadline"
          class="textbox-n"
          type="text"
          onfocus="(this.type='date')"
          onblur="(this.type='text')"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="New-Iteration-Lower-Half">
      <p class="New-Iteration-Files">
        No Files Attached
      </p>
      <p class="New-Iteration-Money">
        $<input
          id="money"
          v-model="value.payoutAmount"
          type="number"
          placeholder="00.00"
          step="0.01"
          min="0"
          name="money"
        />
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and its javascript

```
export default {
  name: 'NewProjectIteration',
  props: ['index', 'value'],
  watch: {
    value() {
      this.$emit('input', this.value)
    }
  }
}
```

Part of me has a feeling it has to do with Vue's lifestyle hooks and I'm using them incorrectly. Regardless I wanted to ask this question in case that anyone else would ever run into the same problem as me and wanted to read a detailed response.

Comment: You have a prop naming value. but you have not passed any value in parent component, I executed your code and got this error.

Comment: This is due to v-model’s syntactic sugar. v-model is just :value=“” @input=“(Input) = this.$emit(‘input’)” if im not mistaking. Regardless, even if I passed in a prop named :value, I still get an error.